# Is this a $\pi$-system?

Tags: measure-theory

Consider $\mathcal{F}=\{\emptyset, \{1,2,3\}, \{4,5,6\}, \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\}$. Is this a $\pi$-system?

My understanding is we need for $A,B\in\mathcal{F}$, $A\cap B\in\mathcal{F}$. My guess is all bases are covered here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is true by inspection: either the elements are disjoint (and $\emptyset$ is in $\mathcal{F}$ so that's fine) or contained in each other so that the intersection is the smallest one.